# Why customized getkey() function is not working in java?

Tags: hashmap

I made `getKey()` function to get a key from `HashMap<ArrayList<String>,String>` variable.

But It is not working, I totally don't know why it is not working.

```
private ArrayList<String> getKey(String value) {
        Iterator<ArrayList<String>> it=history_map.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            if(history_map.get(it.next()).equals(value)) {
                return it.next();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

value is "Function". and `history_map` has key type `ArrayList<String>`.

So I find value comparing every value of key. What is the problem?

It always return `null` value.

I use this function in below.

```
public void setFunction(String function) {
        getKey("Function").add(function);
    }
    public void setEnergyLevel(int energy) {
        getKey("EnergyLevel").add(String.valueOf(energy));
    }
    public void setTemperature(int temp) {
        getKey("Temperature").add(String.valueOf(temp));
    }
    public void setHumidity(int hum) {
        getKey("Humidity").add(String.valueOf(hum));
    }
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        getKey("Fastest speed").add(String.valueOf(speed));
    }
```

Comment: how does history_map looks like ?

Comment: `HashMap<ArrayList<String>,String> history_map`

Comment: Isn't your map the wrong way around? Shouldn't it have `String` keys and `ArrayList<String>` values?

Comment: @bizclop I changed key to `String`, it works thank you

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be inside the if:

```
if(history_map.get(it.next()).equals(value)) {
      return it.next();
}
```

If the match is found, iterators next() method is **called again while executing return statement**. If map consist of single key, then it will throw java.util.NoSuchElementException.